# Do migrations make sense when the database is changed externally?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm thinking about using migrations with Entity Framework. The thing is that someone else, an external colleague is changing columns on his own, so the migration would not do any changes in the database by using update-database, because it's already done.

Is there any sense to use migrations in such a case?

Comment: Mixing (automatic) migrations with manual manipulation of the db schema doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Is there a good reason why your colleague is changing the database by hand?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Yes, i think so too, that it's not a good idea. There are company internal reasons why it's only working this way. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience not. Manual changes in DB structure can sometimes really mess up next migrations to be applied. Best way is to get to an agreement in your company that will set rules how DBs are maintained. This agreement needs to be honored, because you won't be able to replicate any changes made by hand if the application is deployed to other environments. Even worse, after some changes you might not be able to apply newest migration at all (because the DB snapshots won't fit), and this implies lots of unnecessary investigation and work.